# Fake group filtering in Crossfilter / dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to understand the "fake group" filtering method as described in the dc.js FAQ [How do I filter the data before it's charted?](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted)

Please see my example here: [dc.js jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/men_in_ven/wzrqahyz/)

I want to filter my data by TYPE before the charts are drawn (the TYPE to filter on will come from another part of my application). Basically it should have the same effect as clicking on one of the four bars (A,B,C,D) in the row chart, but I want to be able to control it from elsewhere in my code, and it should happen before the charts are drawn.

I think I need to use the [Filter out bins by predicate function on the values](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-out-bins-by-a-predicate-function-on-the-values) approach on my group named "type" e.g.

```
function filter_bins(source_group, f) {
return {
    all:function () {
        return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
            return f(d.value);
        });
    }
};
```

}

But I'm unclear on what function I should be passing in as f, or what a predicate function is.

I would appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to truly behave as if the type was clicked in the `typeRowChart` (this is probably what you want), then do this anywhere you want:

```
typeRowChart.filter("A");
```

If you want the `typeRowChart` to remain as-is (unfiltered) for some reason but you want to filter on the typeDim, then filter directly on the dimension and call `dc.redrawAll()`:

```
typeDim.filter("A");
dc.redrawAll();
```

If you want `typeRowChart` to be filtered by the new selection as well, then create a new type dimension and filter on that:

```
var typeDim2 = cf.dimension(function (d) {return d.TYPE;});
typeDim2.filter("A");
dc.redrawAll();
```

I don't think there is a need for the fake-group pattern in this scenario, fortunately. :-)

Comment: Right, the fake group would be if you want the group not to show up on the screen, but also not to filter. I guess it's confusing that the FAQ uses the word "filter" for a different operation, will have to think about that.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! Out of curiousity, in what scenario would you want to use the fake group pattern?

Comment: You'd use that pattern if you wanted to exclude a group for a specific chart but not have a global filter in place, or otherwise modify a group for the purposes of use in a single chart. You can also use the .data() function to do this in some cases, but my understanding is that can step on other functionality sometimes.